# DynamoDB Global Secondary Index creation has stalled

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have tried to create a Global Secondary Index on my DynamoDB table that has approximately 600k records in it.

After several hours of indexing, the `OnlineIndexPercentageProgress` metric seems to have stalled at 61% and has been stuck there for nearly 16 hours.

My understanding is that you can reduce the indexing time by increasing Read Capacity Units on the table and Write Capacity Units on the index. I increased both from 5 to 20. But, the index "Item Count" and "Size" seem to be stuck.

Is there something I am doing wrong here? Do I need to increase the RCU and/or WCU more? Why are the "Item Count" and "Size" not increasing?

Comment: I think after 16 hours of no progress I would open a ticket with AWS support. I'm personally not aware of any reason it would completely hang like that for so long.

Answer (score 0):

The best bet for resolution on this particular issue will be to contact AWS support with this exact inquiry.

Comment: Thanks. It did eventually finish soon after posting my question.